Show that if $f: \left[0, 1\right]\times\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is monotone on every horizontal and vertical segment, it is integrable.
I managed to prove the statement if all of the horizontal segments have the same monotonicity, and the vertical segments also have the same monotonicity. For the general case, my idea was to split the square into smaller rectangles by drawing horizontal lines where the functions $g_{y}(x)=f(x,y)$ "change monotonicity" and vertical lines where the functions $h_{x}(y)=f(x,y)$ "change monotonicity", then I can apply the special case to each of these rectangles. I would only need to prove that these functions can only "change monotonicity" at most countably infinitely many times, because then I can really draw these rectangles, integrate $f$ on them, and by the countable additivity of integration, I can integrate $f$ on the whole of  $\left[0, 1\right]\times\left[0,1\right]$.
This may be really simple, but I am not seeing it at the moment. Any help is appreciated!

which integration theory ?  also is $f$ bounded on the unit square, because the 1-dimensional example $\frac 1x$ is monotone yet not integrable, and probably extensible to 2d.

@zwim The assumptions imply boundedness because the square is closed.

A question in advance to the Fifth Close Voter, who inevitably will appear and shut this question down for good: would you be so kind and leave a comment what information exactly you consider missing? Seriously, please don't just smash that close button and furtively walk away like the other four.

First note that if $R = [x_1, x_2] \times [y_1, y_2]$ is any subrectangle of $[0, 1] \times [0,1 ]$, then
$$\begin{align*} \sup_{z \in R} f(z) & = \max \{ f(x_i, y_j) : i, j \in \{ 1, 2 \} \} \\[1ex]
\inf_{z \in R} f(z) & = \min \{ f(x_i, y_j) : i, j \in \{ 1, 2 \} \}\end{align*}$$
and so
$$\begin{align*} \sup_{z \in R} f(z) - \inf_{z \in R} f(z) & = \max \{ f(x_i, y_j) : i, j \in \{ 1, 2 \} \} - \min \{ f(x_i, y_j) : i, j \in \{ 1, 2 \} \} \\[1ex]
& \leqslant |f(x_2, y_2) - f(x_1, y_2)| + |f(x_1, y_2) - f(x_1, y_1)| \\[1ex]
& + |f(x_2, y_2) - f(x_2, y_1)| + |f(x_2, y_1) - f(x_1, y_1)|.
\end{align*}$$
Now consider the partition $\mathcal{P}_n$ of $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ into $n^2$ rectangles of dimensions $\frac{1}{n} \times \frac{1}{n}$. Adding the inequalities above for each rectangle $R \in \mathcal{P}_n$ and using monotonicity on segments we get
$$\begin{align*} U(f, \mathcal{P}_n) - L(f, \mathcal{P}_n) & \leqslant \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{k=0}^n \left| f \left( \frac{k}{n}, 1 \right) - f \left( \frac{k}{n}, 0 \right) \right| + \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{k=0}^n \left| f \left( 1, \frac{k}{n} \right) - f \left( 1, \frac{k}{n} \right) \right| \\[1ex]
& \leqslant \frac{4(n+1)}{n^2} \cdot \left[ \max_{z \in [0, 1]^2} f(z) - \min_{z \in [0, 1]^2} f(z) \right]
\end{align*}$$
where the difference in the square brackets exists because of the initial remark. When $n \to \infty$, the right hand side goes to $0$ and so the function is integrable.
